# How to find or check the MSB of a register using LC-3 instructions?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, lc3

I need to figure out if the MSB of a set of bits in a register is one or zero. How would you go about doing this using LC-3 instructions?

LC-3 Instruction Set:
https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/fussell/courses/cs310h/lectures/Lecture_10-310h.pdf

Comment: I recommend also putting the `assembly` tag.

Comment: Is the allowed instruction only `add`, `and`, and `not`?

Comment: Yes, we are only allowed to use add, and, and not.

Comment: So what do you want as output? Do you want a certain value stored in a register or a certain flag set to a certain value?

Comment: Basically, what im doing is checking how many ones there are in a set of bits. I am checking the msb to see if it is a 1 and then left shifting the entire set. I repeat this process for each of the bits in the set.

Comment: Okay so you need to set a certain flag depending on the MSB and do a conditional jump right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Actually, are you able to just AND the set of bits in the given register by one? Would that give you the MSB?

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use the conditional branch instruction, then you'll need to set the conditions based on the register value.

One way to accomplish setting the conditions is to add 0 to the register — it might seem like adding 0 wouldn't do anything but has the side effect of setting the conditions, `N`, `Z`, and `P`.  There are other ways to get the conditions set, but this is simple and direct.

Once the conditions are set you can conditionally branch on negative, or else on zero-or-positive.  Either way, you can put then/else code after such a conditional branch.